# nano command not found during Mupdf compling

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, mingw, mupdf, nano

I am trying to compiling the latest release (cloned git repo today) of MuPDF library. I am following these steps specifying [Here](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)

**1**.Check out a copy of the mupdf source from git:

git clone git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git

**2**.Check out the third party library submodules:

git submodule update --init

**3**.Populate the generated directory with the necessary files:

make generate

But, when I enter the last command, I got these errors:

`sh.exe make command not found`.
then i download make.exe setup from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm)

then i update environment variable with **C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin**

after that when i enter the command 
make generate

i got

[image]

Then i download Mingw and modify my environment var with **"C:\MinGW\bin"** then i followed these steps :-

4.Change into the android directory and edit the local properties configuration file.

```
~/src/mupdf $ cd android
~/src/mupdf/android $ cp local.properties.sample local.properties
~/src/mupdf/android $ nano local.properties
```

then in last line `~/src/mupdf/android $ nano local.properties` i got this error 
[image: error nano command not found]

Comment: Seems like you don't have a C compiler either. You probably need to install gcc at least.

Comment: nano is an editor for Linux, if you don't have it either install it or use a different editor.

Comment: @Kens I am using Windows 7 do you know any option for windows for it

Comment: You aren't using Windows 7, you are using Cygwin, or MingW. However I believe both of those can launch Windows applications, so just use Notepad. Or, of course, edit the file from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

msysgit has vim integrated, if it sounds too complex try Notepad++ from Windows. Notepad might not work, as the file may use or required *nix newline.